# Error SC424 connecting Make.com to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, make.com

Ive added a new api app in GCS for GA4 & UA data connection to make.com. I granted credentials and added google analytics scope. The authorised redirect URI I used was https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/google/. I keep getting the following error when trying to connect make.com via the OAuth 2.0 module:

{"message":"The request failed due to failure of a previous request.","code":"SC424","suberrors":[{"message":"Account error (invalid_request)","name":"Error"}]}

Comment: I'm facing the same response error code with twitter app